# email signup multiple lists

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have the following code, I want the user to be able to sign up to multiple lists at the same time. It is currently only signing up emails to one list randomly, even if I check all the lists. Is it possible to do? Maybe some sort of php echo?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="accName" type="hidden" value="companyname">
    <input name="listName" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="fullEmailValidationInd" type="hidden" value="Y">
    <input name="doubleOptin" type="hidden" value="false">
    <input name="successUrl" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="errorUrl" type="hidden" value="">
    Email Address <input class="border" name="email" size='50' type="text" value="">
    First Name <input class="border" name="First_Name" size='50' type="text" value=""> 
    Last Name <input class="border" name="Last_Name" size='50' type="text" value="">
    <label><input name="listName" type="checkbox" value="list1"></label>
    <label><input name="listName" type="checkbox" value="list2"></label>
    <label><input name="listName" type="checkbox" value="list3"></label>
    <label><input name="listName" type="checkbox" value="list4"></label>
    <label><input name="listName" type="checkbox" value="list5"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: Turn `listName` into an array `listName[]`. I'll let you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Use array for the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" NAME="listName[]" VALUE="list1"  />
```

Or use different names...

You will need to grab this using, php side, a loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['listName'] as $selected)
```

Just notice that if none are selected this will fail, thus check if the array exists before:

```
if (isset($_POST['listName'])
{
    foreach ($_POST['listName'] as selected)
    {
        DO YOUR STUFF
    }
}
```